# Add Shipping class below each product in WooCommerce Shopping Cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I've configure shipping class for my products. But I want to display them below each product in the shopping cart page. Something like this :

[image]

Can this be done through editing the PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display the product shipping class name in cart page, there is many ways to do it:

1) Using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_cart_item_name`** filter hook, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'shipping_class_in_item_name', 20, 2 );
function shipping_class_in_item_name( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {

    $custom_items = array();

    $product = $cart_item['data']; // Get the WC_Product object instance
    $shipping_class_id = $product->get_shipping_class_id(); // Shipping class ID
    $shipping_class_term = get_term( $shipping_class_id, 'product_shipping_class' );
    $label = __( 'Shipping class', 'woocommerce' );

    // Checking (To display it in checkout page too, remove below " || is_checkout()" )
    if( empty( $shipping_class_id ) || is_checkout() )
        return $cart_data; // Return default cart dat (in case of)

    // If product or variation description exists we display it
    $custom_items[] = array(
        'key'      => $label,
        'display'  => $shipping_class_term->name,
    );

    // Merging shipping class name and product variation attributes + values (if there are some)
    if( ! empty( $cart_data ) ) $custom_items = array_merge( $custom_items, $cart_data );

    return $custom_items;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

This code is tested and works.

---

2) Using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_cart_item_name`** filter hook, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'shipping_class_in_item_name', 20, 3);
function shipping_class_in_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Only in cart page (remove the line below to allow the display in checkout too)
    if( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) return $item_name;

    $product = $cart_item['data']; // Get the WC_Product object instance
    $shipping_class_id = $product->get_shipping_class_id(); // Shipping class ID
    $shipping_class_term = get_term( $shipping_class_id, 'product_shipping_class' );

    if( empty( $shipping_class_id ) )
        return $item_name; // Return default product title (in case of)

    $label = __( 'Shipping class', 'woocommerce' );

    return $item_name . '<br>
        <p class="item-shipping_class" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
            <strong>' .$label . ': </strong>' . $shipping_class_term->name . '</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: How to add the price after address input, next to the shipping class title.

Comment: This is too complicated as it depends on your shipping settings, the customer choice, the defined customer location and for example if you have multiple items in cart for each different shipping classes, the calculation is just a nightmare. Also if you use formulas in that shipping classes costs settings by shipping method, it's even worth… So what you are asking is a real development, so something too broad, as you don't provide any related code intent.