# How to get total shipping fee in checkout page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove the shipping row in check out page whenever the shipping total price is 0.
[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYBFJ.png)

For now this is the code I got.
This code allows to hide the shipping row, Using the shipping fee I can create condition to hide it on check out page. Thank you

```
function disable_shipping_calc_on_cart($show_shipping) {
if(is_checkout()){
return false;
}
return $show_shipping;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping', 'disable_shipping_calc_on_cart', 99 );
```

Comment: Can you read the question properly @GufranHasan? The question is very specific.

Comment: Okay, you can add this filter to hide shipping when it's total 0. `woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add this filter `woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label` in `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'add_free_shipping_label', 10, 2 );
    function add_free_shipping_label( $label, $method ) {
        if ( is_checkout() && $method->cost == 0 ) {
            echo '<style>tr.shipping{display:none;}</style>';
        }
        return $label;
    }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655887/how-to-show-zero-rate-value-of-shipping-class-in-cart-page-woocommerce)

Comment: how can i get the the shipping class id using this $method?

Comment: Please see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353893/add-shipping-class-below-each-product-in-woocommerce-shopping-cart-page