# How to show shipping method in Woocommerce products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I am using *[Add Shipping class below each product in WooCommerce Shopping Cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353893/add-shipping-class-below-each-product-in-woocommerce-shopping-cart-page/48355618#48355618)* 2nd function answer code. It's working like a charm but I would like to associate products shipping method also in shop page and single product page.

Comment: please share what you have already tried

Comment: Nothing, i haven’t tried anything. I searched anykey button but couldn’t find it. Apparently LoicTheAztec removed his answer to protect his reputation or something, lol. 